# Mass add users AD with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2016, powershell-ise

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$file = "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\UsersHR.csv"
$targetDN = "OU=HR,OU=NTTLab,DC=NTTLab,DC=internal"

$importedUsers = Import-Csv $file
foreach ($user in $importedUsers)
{
    $Username   = $User.Username
    $Password   = $User.Password
    $Firstname  = $User.Firstname
    $Lastname   = $User.Surname
    $Name       = $User.Firstname + $User.Lastname
    $OU         = "OU=HR,OU=NTTLab,DC=NTTLab,DC=internal" 
    $company    = $User.company
    $department = $User.department
    $Password = $User.Password

New-ADUser -SamAccountName $Username -Name $Name -GivenName $Firstname -Surname $Lastname -Enabled $true -DisplayName "$Lastname, $Firstname" -Path $OU -Company $Company -Department $department -AccountPassword $Password -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
}
```

I'm working on a VM of windows server 2016.
I'm trying to add several users at once to the AD using PowerShell ISE, but I'm running into several errors about the name.
it's either not properly formed, empty or it's asking for it manually

Comment: Do not add sensitive information when asking questions.

Comment: When you say that something didn't work, you have to say _how_ it didn't work. (Remember, nobody can see your screen.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what it's complaining about, but I assume it's this:

```
 $Username   = $User.Username
 ...
 New-ADUser -SamAccountName $Username
```

There are several [User Naming Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/naming-properties) in Active Directory. The [`sAMAccountName` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-samaccountname) is a short username. It must be 20 characters or less. Although the `@` character is technically allowed, it is usually never used. In fact, AD Users and Computers won't let you put an `@` in it.

That "Username" you have in your file is a better fit for the [`userPrincipalName` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-userprincipalname).

But you will still have to figure something out for the `sAMAccountName`. Our organization uses the last name (cropped at 18 characters) and first two letters of the first name. That would look something like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$file = "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\UsersHR.csv"
$targetDN = "OU=HR,OU=NTTLab,DC=NTTLab,DC=internal"

$importedUsers = Import-Csv $file
foreach ($user in $importedUsers)
{
    $SamAccountName     = "$($User.Surname.Substring(0, [System.Math]::Min(18, $User.Surname.Length)))$($User.Firstname)"
    $UserPrincipalName  = $User.Username
    $Password           = $User.Password
    $Firstname          = $User.Firstname
    $Lastname           = $User.Surname
    $Name               = "$($User.Firstname) $($User.Surname)"
    $OU                 = "OU=HR,OU=NTTLab,DC=NTTLab,DC=internal" 
    $company            = $User.company
    $department         = $User.department
    $Password           = $User.Password

    New-ADUser -SamAccountName $SamAccountName -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -Name $Name -GivenName $Firstname -Surname $Lastname -Enabled $true -DisplayName "$Lastname, $Firstname" -Path $OU -Company $Company -Department $department -AccountPassword $Password -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
}
```

I also fixed how you defined `$Name`, since it didn't have a space, and you were using `$User.Lastname` instead of `$User.Surname`.

Comment: I do think that this solved some of the issues. but now it's complaining about "New-ADUser : the parameter is incorrect"

Comment: It doesn't tell you which parameter?

Comment: it just points to the whole line. can i break up the line into several lines without breaking how it works? then i could see which it's pointing too

Comment: You can put a `\`` at the end of a line to show that it continues on the next line, but I don't think that would help. It would probably always tell you the line where `Set-ADUser` starts. If you can do this multiple times, you can remove parameters one at a time until it stops complaining. Then just delete whatever account it created so you can do it properly again later.

Comment: it appears to work without "-Enabled $True" and "-Name $Name" it also doesn't appear to fill in firstname, lastname or anything except the name when i give that manually. it does give a ". " in the display name

Comment: i've found a way to do it. not sure what i changed. i just started with the minimum and added things in every iteration